# TypeScript: Merge generic parameters of union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want the `bar` method to automatically merge the generic type parameters of `Foo`, because else the `baz` method will throw an error:

```
Each member of the union type '(<TBaz extends string>(value: TBaz) => void) | (<TBaz extends number>(value: TBaz) => void)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

Here's some code that reproduces the error:

```
interface Foo<TX, TY> {
  bar<TFoo extends Foo<unknown, unknown>>(mapper: (value: TX) => TFoo): TFoo;
  baz<TBaz extends TY>(value: TBaz): void
}

const x = null as unknown as Foo<'1', number>;

const y = x.bar(x => {
  if(x) {
    return null as unknown as Foo<'2', number>;
  } else {
    return null as unknown as Foo<'3', string>;
  }
});

// y is Foo<'2', number> | Foo<'3', string>
// but baz needs it as Foo<'2' | '3', number | string>

const z = y.baz('2');
// `z` is typed as `void` as expected
```

The error can be worked around by manually providing the generic type `Foo<'2'|'3',string|number>` when calling `bar`, but I'd like TypeScript to handle that for me without explicitly specifying it every time.

I've tried to use `infer` to extract the generic parameters and then recreate the type, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
bar<TFoo extends Foo<unknown, unknown>>(mapper: (value: TX) => TFoo): TFoo extends Foo<infer X, infer Y> ? Foo<X, Y> : never;
```

Is there any way to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to call a function with a union type, TypeScript treats it as attempting to call the a function that is an intersection of all members of that union. The reason for this is that it must be possible for the call to fire on *any* of the types that function could have.

Historically this has come up most often when dealing with array methods on arrays with union types, such as `number[] | string[]`. For example:

```js
const myArr: number[] | string[] = [];

const el = myArr.find((el) => el === 3);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUC4ZgK5wEYCmKA2gLowA+M0KAlmAOZkwC8MZA3ALABQvokWAQA2reMjQA6AGb0AJgAoFIgJSsAfDBGsWbAMwruPIA)

TypeScript 5.2 (currently in beta) changes this behaviour to allow functions like this to be treated still as a union type, which prevents this error. *However*, this is treated as a special case for array methods, and other functions won't benefit from this change.

For more information, see [Announcing TypeScript 5.2 Beta: Easier Method Usage for Unions of Arrays](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2-beta/#easier-method-usage-for-unions-of-arrays)

As far as I'm aware, the only real way around this is to use a type assertion. You might want to try something like this:

```js
interface Foo<TX, TY> {
  bar<TFoo extends Foo<unknown, unknown>>(mapper: (value: TX) => TFoo): TFoo;
  baz<TBaz extends TY>(value: TBaz): void
}

const x = null as unknown as Foo<'1', number>;

const y = x.bar(x => {
  if(x) {
    return null as unknown as Foo<'2', number>;
  } else {
    return null as unknown as Foo<'3', string>;
  }
});

// y is Foo<'2', number> | Foo<'3', string>
// but baz needs it as Foo<'2' | '3', number | string>

type FooWithInternalUnion<T extends Foo<unknown, unknown>> = [T] extends ([Foo<infer TXA, infer TYA>] | [Foo<infer TXB, infer TYB>]) ? Foo<TXA | TXB, TYA | TYB> : never;

const z = (y as FooWithInternalUnion<typeof y>).baz('2');
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#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-j9IA9kZI-mDdgA-KT8N6hVGiIHMwmKIYQBBjNAUbQcnkCsErWpRhz0HLFSrIHtNdrdZK9OgYCMyDZJkE1LjkUA)

In the `FooWithInternalUnion` utility type, the tuple types are used internally to prevent the distributive property from applying over each member of the union individually. Without it, the type won't actually modify your union type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! The `FooWithInternalUnion` type looks interesting, but I guess it'll only work with a Union of `2` (?) types, or can it magically scale to a Union of `n` types, by just applying the transformation pairwise? `...` All in all it seems like overriding the generic by calling ´bar<MyFoo>` would result in the least noisy code - until they maybe provide the new 5.2 feature for other types as well.

Comment: I did write  it specifically for a union of two types, but updating the example so the union has three members (or four, and presumably more as well) it seems to work just as well. I'm not sure I know how to explain that behaviour though sorry, I had thought I'd need to change how the utility type works to make it recursive in order to accomplish that.

Comment: Opening the playground and putting the cursor over that final `z`, it shows `const z: void`.  Is that expected?  Is it OK?

Comment: It's expected. In the `Foo` definition at the top, the `baz` method is defined with a `void` return type. You're right that you wouldn't usually assign this to a variable, so it seems wrong. But the internals of `Foo` don't really contribute to the problem, it's only important that this method uses the generic type in its arguments.

Comment: Assuming that futher code somewhere after the `z` declaration uses `z`, it will either cause a type checking error or not be correctly type checked.  So expected but not OK?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's expected because of how the types are defined, but perhaps not the best choice of example. You shouldn't do anything with a `void` type so there's no point in storing it. But the problem being examined here is exactly the same if you just remove `const z = ` and leave the rest the same.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just stripped down my real code, where `baz` actually returns something, but forgot to remove the assignment in the example. Assigning `void` to a variable doesn't really hurt, because TypeScript will prevent you from using it. I'll add a small comment in the code of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a simpler starting point expressing what I think is the core problem you are addressing.  Even if not, maybe it is helpful.

```
// Problem defintion
declare function f1(a:'1'): number;
declare function f2(a:'2'): string;

function g(a:'1'|'2'){
   if (a==='1') return f1;
   else return f2;
}  
g("1")("1"); // error, but it was ugly anyway.

function h(a:'1'|'2'){
   if (a==='1') return f1(a);
   else return f2(a);
}
// no error but mixed types are dumb
h; // function h(a: '1' | '2'): string | number 
h("1"); // string | number
```

Assuming that is not desirable because the types are mixed then the following template interface with overloads would produce the right unmixed result types.

```
// Generic template solution for 2 functions, one parameter each
type Y<F1 extends (a:any)=>any,F2 extends (a:any)=>any,A1=Parameters<F1>[0], R1=ReturnType<F1>, A2=Parameters<F2>[0], R2=ReturnType<F2>> = {
  h(a:A1):R1;
  h(a:A2):R2;
  h(a:A1|A2):R1|R2;
}

declare function f1(a:'1'): number;
declare function f2(a:'2'): string;
const y: Y<typeof f1, typeof f2> = {
  h(a){
    // start Black Box impl
    // Because it is a black box, no qualms about intermediate casting with any
    if (a==="1") return f1(a) as any;
    else return f2(a) as any;
    // end of Black Box
  }
}
const r1 = y.h('1'); // no error, type is number
const r2 = y.h('2'); // no error, type is string
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIEYAKKALgHIDyBKU+VZAWwCMQYBuAKFElgRXTY8SAEwkKImnQDOGGFlQBzLhgCeABwQBNADwAxAvBAAPDCFTBp8cVFSrqAXgB8t1QBo9Io6fOXrZV0cXOzcAQQIHAAVYKEYQMxhpfQInAG0ABgBdN3gAJQjc+OQYVAAVDRBkpxzQkSiYuISkzzSsnNy6woxisor9EScneAd4AG9OeHgAC3Fw2nyuSZmyWvmRRenZggAfVdJ87Y6uAF9OMDxZeFU6XTVNHERCHLuQB9EhkfGlkmovyfgAPQA+CyWAYeAAIWgYAA1pCcMZ4FhGOoIBN-kDIeAoMhpAgsOCsFYoPBmNC4cwETlUDh4ABHZBQCCMYmU5CE1AJOLALBQMzwMBQWQKRTwADuBKm8Fc6MmWEeJAcSoARARldR4HBuiVCD9pcS7BtJiAIHjNUUdYgxFANULpYbZYDgb54G8oVBYfDjOjTqdzqhLjBDCNVAA6GaUGjsJ30WlsGA4GDPCpIqwMFhsM4XcEwLwh8NEciSajRzE0owwBNJ+AvVMguQizhAA)

Consider that the implementation of the template interface is black box, and only the template interface type is exposed.  In my book, that enough to be considered a type safe working solution, and not a hack.

I've tried to modify the solution to work for any number of parameters but so far it won't allow spreading in the override definitions, and requires override functions `h` to be taking a single array parameter - as shown here:

```
// Generic template solution for 2 functions, any number of parameters each
type Y<F1 extends (a:any)=>any,F2 extends (a:any)=>any,A1=Parameters<F1>, R1=ReturnType<F1>, A2=Parameters<F2>, R2=ReturnType<F2>> = {
  h(a:A1):R1;
  h(a:A2):R2;
  h(a:A1|A2):R1|R2;
}

declare function f1(a:'1',n?:number): number;
declare function f2(a:'2'): string;
const y: Y<typeof f1, typeof f2> = {
  h(args){
    // start Black Box impl
    // Because it is a black box, no qualms about intermediate casting with any
    if (args[0]==="1") return f1(args[0]) as any;
    else return f2(args[0]) as any;
    // end of Black Box
  }
}
const r1 = y.h(['1',999]); // no error, type is number
const r1b = y.h(['1']); // no error, type is number
const r2 = y.h(['2']); // no error, type is string
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIEYAKKALgHIDyAaVAflNWQFsAjEGASlPibY4DcAKFCRYCFOmx4kAJhIVZ5bvADOGGFlQBzYRgCeABwQBNADwAxAvBAAPDCFTBV8BVFT7OAXgB87-dQWsjb2js6uZP7efh7UAIIEXgAKsFDMIA4wqpYEPtTwAEqJBRnIMKgAKkYgOXnwcbLJqemZ2UF1BY0lGGWV1ZayPj7wXvAA3kLw8AAWCgncRcJTs2QNC7JLM3MEAD5rpEU7ncIAvkJgeOrw+jzmBsY4iIT59yCPcsOjE8skMNqqnG+U3gAHoQWoMLAMPAAELQMAAa1hOFs8CwzEMEEmwLBsPAUGQqgQWGhWBcUHgrHhSNYKPyqBw8AAjsgoBBmOTachSahMulgFgoA54GAoOotNp4AB3EnTeD+bFTLBPX7-ADaAAYALpeXUAIgIes48DgPXKhFVqk1WuNYvlHk2UxAECJJtK5sQ8lg6u1tvJDsVoPBYXg7zhUERyNs2LOZwuqCuMGso30ADpZmrKDQAJy5m0CIO8RkcGA4GAvapolx8dgwc6XaFJ1gja7poiZqj5wsMmwwUvl+CvKu8Fi1+sJxvBFNtzNKLu4nslssV4zD9SaHRCIA)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
interface Foo<TX, TY> {
  bar<TFoo extends Foo<unknown, unknown>>(mapper: (value: TX) => TFoo): TFoo;
  baz<TBaz extends TY>(value: TBaz): void;
  baz<TBaz extends TY[]>(value: TBaz): void; // New overload for union types
}

type MergeFooTypes<T extends Foo<any, any>[]> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? First extends Foo<infer X, infer Y>
    ? Rest extends Foo<infer XRest, infer YRest>[]
      ? Foo<X | XRest, Y | YRest>
      : never
    : never
  : never;

const x = null as unknown as Foo<'1', number>;

const y = x.bar(x => {
  if (x) {
    return null as unknown as Foo<'2', number>;
  } else {
    return null as unknown as Foo<'3', string>;
  }
});

const z = y.baz('2'); // z is inferred as Foo<'2' | '3', number | string>
```